# If category id = x AND if there is an entry then display

Tags: conditionals

I have a list of images in 4 different categories that I want to display on a search results page. My logic is that the pictures are to be displayed under 2 conditions,
1 - it is in its respective category id, 2 - there are actually entries that have that category.

```
{if "{category_id}" == "1" &&  count >= "1"}
Image group 1 
{/if}
{if "{category_id}" == "2" &&  count >= "1"}
Image group 2 
{/if}
```

This code is not working,I think I'm messing up the syntax.

Some more code:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="product" category_group="1" style="linear"   parent_only="yes" show="{embed:prod_cat}" show_empty="no"}
{if count == '1'}
<ul class="tabs-nav clearfix">
{/if} 
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_{category_url_title}">{category_name} Product<span class="indicator">        </span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="logo-strip">
        {!-- v neck tees --}
        {if "{category_id}" == "1"}
        <!-- Nike -->
        <img src="/images/logos/nike.jpg" class="float-left">
        <!-- Adidas -->
        <img src="/images/logos/adidas.jpg" class="float-left"> 
        <!-- Cat -->
        <img src="/images/logos/cat.jpg" class="float-left"> 
        {/if}

        {!-- long sleeve tees --}
        {if "{category_id}" == "2"} 
        <!-- Puma -->
        <img src="/images/logos/cat.jpg" class="float-left"> 
        <!-- Lacoste -->
         <img src="/images/logos/lacoste.jpg" class="float-left cat_2">
        {/if}

    </li>  

    {if count == total_results}
</ul><!-- end nav -->
{/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you need. Can you, please, add more info? Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I have a page with products on them. Each product is in one of 4 categories. I have a set of logos that correspond with the brand of that product. The category number (category id) is what determines what logo gets shown. So if the product is in category 1 then display these logos (image group 1). Now I also need the condition that these logos only show if there are products to view.

Comment: Still need more information - is the code above standalone on the page or is it nested within the channel:entries loop?  You state the page has products on, are you showing the logos in a sidebar as a collective, or within each product display? Is it in a {categories} variable pair, or {exp:channel:categories} tag pair? If in a channel:entries -> {categories} variable pair, remove the '&& count >= "1"' part of the conditional as it will only be hitting the conditional if there's a product that is in that category.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't say "what" isn't working so I'm going to add here what "should" work without knowing the extent of what you're doing.

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="product" category_group="1" style="linear" parent_only="yes" show="{embed:prod_cat}" show_empty="no"}
    {if category_id == "1"}
        Image group 1 
    {/if}
    {if category_id == "2"}
        Image group 2 
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Since you have the parameter `show_empty="no"` set, categories without entries shouldn't be returned. `{if category_id == "1"}` then controls which image shows for the category ID.

If results are not returning correctly, it's possible the `show="{embed:prod_cat}"` parameter is causing your problems.